# How to handle errors in Admin SDK initializeApp with node?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

If I use the following code with the Admin SDK

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: '<PROJECT_ID>',
    clientEmail: 'foo@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
    privateKey: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n<KEY>\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
  }),
  databaseURL: 'https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com'
});
```

How am I going to know if it failed? For some reason there's no mention about handling success/error in the docs which I find very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll know it failed because it will crash with a meaningful error message in the output of your program.  The only way init can fail is if you haven't configured the admin SDK properly.  Initialization doesn't actually try to reach the database or do anything else that could fail.  Other failures will be seen be rejected promises from other API calls you make.